# How do I make a oval(ellipsoid) dome structure?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, edit-mode

I am trying to model the National Center for the Performing Arts in Beijing. It's an ellipsoid structure and I'm using arrays and curve. Each radius is different cause it's oval. Is there an easier way to model it?
I think I already messed up because of it's rotation.

Minor Radian 72.5 meters
Major Radian 106 meters
Height 46 meters

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: Reference image]
[image: Reference image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, so do you have a picture that shows the whole thing? how it goes all around?

Comment: seems hard to do, you could do it with some arrays + curve modifier + simple deform, but it won't be correct because it will reduce the size of the segments and I don't think that's what happens...